# iOS7.0の検証方法と対象OSが搭載されている実機について

Tags: ios, xcode

昨年の後半からiOSの開発を始めた者です。
現在iOS7以降対応のアプリを作成しているのですが、Xcode6ではシミュレータが7.1以降しか対応しておらず、7.0の検証手段がありません。

古いバージョンのXcodeから7.0のSDKを持ってくるという情報もありましたが、OSX yosemiteでは対応していないのか、試してみたところシミュレータを起動しても真っ暗なままになってしまいます。

そこで第一に"OSX yosemiteの環境でiOS7.0のシミュレータを動作させる方法があるのか"お聞きしたいです。

またシミュレータが動作するにせよ細かいUIを調整するには実機が必要だと考えているのですが、現在iOS7.0が動作する端末を入手することはできるのでしょうか？

ipod touch第5世代をアップデートすることでiOS6からiOS7以降にすることはできるようですが、懸念材料としてiOS7.1に一気にジャンプアップしてしまうのではないかということがあります。

二点目として"iOS7.0が搭載された実機の入手方法"についてもお聞きしたいです。
回答のほど、よろしくお願い致しします。

Answer (score 3):

**OSX yosemiteの環境でiOS7.0のシミュレータを動作させる方法があるのか？**

Apple公式のソースとしては見当たりませんでしたが、[本家stackoverflowに同様の質問があり](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1)、`iOS Simulator`に携わっているとされる方が、

> The iOS 7.0 simulator does not work on OSX Yosemite, so you need to be on OS X Mavericks if you want to run the iOS 7.0 simulator.

と回答しています。

MavericksのXCode6βの時点ですと7.0のシミュレータがありますが、XCode6.1ではダウンロードできなくなっています。

**iOS7.0が搭載された実機の入手方法**

正規の方法でiOS7.0.Xを復元する方法は恐らくなく、新品として手に入れることは難しいと思います。

中古販売のiOS端末にはOSバージョンが明記されているので、7.0.Xの実機を入手すること自体は難しくないと思います。

「UIの調整」として求められる要件がどの程度か分かりませんが、[iOS7.0.2までとiOS7.0.3からでは`UINavigationBar`に`tintColor`を設定した場合の挙動が違う](http://qiita.com/yimajo/items/4781d5d2712e34677db2)などありますので、本当に微細な部分までサポートするのであれば、初期のメンテナンスバージョンを手に入れる必要があります。スペックの低い端末だとなお良いでしょう。

なお、[2015年1月現在でiOS7.Xの割合は28％](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/)です。7.1と7.0の利用者の割合は非公開ですが、多くても半数程度でしょうか。