# Xcode 6.3でiOS 8.0及び7.0のシミュレーターを実行したい

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

Xcode 6.3にて、iOS 8.0及びiOS 7.0のシミュレーターを実行する方法はありますか？

公式配布されているのが7.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3の4種のみのため、
7.0, 8.0での動作確認ができません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[iOS7.0の検証方法と対象OSが搭載されている実機について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5194)
OSがYosemiteだったら7.0は難しい（不可能？）と思います。

本家SOにあった同じような[質問（How to install iOS 7.0 and iOS 8.0 Simulators in Xcode 6.1?）](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491922/how-to-install-ios-7-0-and-ios-8-0-simulators-in-xcode-6-1)（6ヶ月前のXcode6.1についての質問ですが・・・）には下記回答がついていましたが、iOS8.0も難しそうな気はします。

> The iOS 8.0 simulator is not supported any more as of the release of Xcode 6.1.
>   If you really want it, you can either install Xcode 6.0 or you can try copying the iPhoenSimulator8.0.sdk and iOS 8.0.simruntime from Xcode 6.0 into Xcode 6.1, but as stated, this is not supported.

参考訳

> iOS 8.0 シミュレーターは、Xcode 6.1 の公開をもってサポートされなくなりました。
>   どうしても必要なら Xcode6.0 を併用したり、iPhoenSimulator8.0.sdk と iOS 8.0.simruntime を Xcode 6.0 からコピーしてみることはできますが、前述のとおりサポート対象外です。

Comment: 機械翻訳よりはまだ読みやすいかなと思い訳を置き換えてみました。

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます。ものすごく助かります。